# Use jQuery to scroll to display element which was loaded in via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a script which gets images via AJAX and then displays them on the page in a div called #media-area, which has a fixed height and `overflow: scroll;`. With this, user's can select an image. On some pages, the image will already be selected. In this case I want the div to scroll so the selected image is positioned along the top.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?c=media&m=media_ajax',
    success: function (res) {
        for (var index in res) {
            var me = res[index];

            var html = '<div class="col-md-3"><input type="radio" name="medialibrary" id="medialibrary' + me.id + '" value="' + me.id + '">';
            html += '<label for="medialibrary' + me.id + '">';
            html += '<img src="/image.php?image=' + me.image + '&thumbnail=122,122" alt="' + me.name + '" id="img_medialibrary' + me.id + '" width="122" height="122">';
            html += '</a>';
            html += '</div>';

            $("#media-area").append(html);

            $("#medialibrary" + me.id).change(function () {
                window.selected = $(this).val();
                $("#ml_selected").val($(this).val());
                $("#clear-selection").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#upload").hide();
            });

            if ($("#ml_selected").val() == me.id) {
                $("#clear-selection").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#upload").hide();
                $("#medialibrary" + me.id).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
        }

        $('#media-area input').each(function () {
            var radioInput = $(this);
            if (radioInput.is(':checked')) {
                var radioIMG = $("#img_" + radioInput.attr('id'));
                $('#media-area').animate({
                    scrollTop: radioIMG.offset().top
                }, 2000);

            }
        });

    }
});
```

I can get the div to scroll, but it won't be anywhere near the selected div. I'm guessing this is because the images haven't fully loaded when scroll event is fired. How would I go about running this event to scroll to the selected item after all images have been loaded in via AJAX?

Comment: An image has a .load event (JQuery) which will only fire when the image is fully loaded. EDIT: The <img /> tag to be specific.

Comment: Is there any way to fire this .load event once _all_ the images have loaded? I did try using `.on('load', function(){  });` but to no avail as some images would load after others, messing up where the div scrolled to.

Comment: If you polyfill, `Promise.all` would work.

Comment: Brilliant, that's sorted it. Thanks!